# Angular 6 Cache layer

Tags: angular, caching, angular6

Scenario

1. Multiple CodeTables only needed to be imported once
2. Need to check from time to time if the code tables has been edited at the back-end.
3. I want to be able to save it in localStorage

---

- I need it to work on IOS , Android and PC (

so storages are a challenge platform-wise.

In IOS, as I understand, there is an issue accessing localStorage, as well as when Android memory is too full
).
Maybe set dynamic storage by platform.

Found this solution
Simple not complete
https://nrempel.com/guides/angular-httpclient-httpinterceptor-cache-requests/

Probably to complicated
https://hackernoon.com/angular-simple-in-memory-cache-service-on-the-ui-with-rxjs-77f167387e39

> Any other good and simple solution without magics?

I think maybe combining the 
https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-caching-http-interceptor
caching http interceptor with storage as parameter 
and then enabling me to save the data on cache or storage such as localStorage or dbStorage  of somekind..

Comment: If you want manage complex table use IndexedDB, you can check JSstore http://ujjwalguptaofficial.blogspot.com/2017/10/angular4-crud-operation-in-indexeddb.html or "googlear"

Comment: It is not complex. It's just a lot of tables.
Like 20 tables with codes that now i get each time.
I want them to be saved once the app/website is up and check themselves if they change.

Comment: Im pretty sure that you can use Service Workers with Data Groups to cache API external calls, search for the topic, I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: With 20 tables, I would use IndexedDB -not LocalStore-. There are some librarys that make easy manage indexedDB. JsStore is one of them. I used in a project with Angular 5 and work fine -the idea was make an app in Android and PC-

Comment: @dAxx_  can you state relevant link for angular 6 and .net core 2.1 ? it's like an ocean of data out there.. hard to find specifically what you refer to

Comment: @Eliseo does IndexDb work on IOS and Android with PWA SPA Angular 6 ?

Comment: I used with Cordova for Android, Angular 5, using the template of Cordova from Visual Studio 2017 Community (copying the dist folder created by angular-cli in wwwroot). -it's my only experience :( -